# How to insert a reference type field on Firestore with Golang

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore

Inside my database i'm using fields of reference type on some documents, like this:

[image: Field of type reference]

I'm trying to insert these property on firestore

```golang
    _, err = userReference.Set(context.Background(), models.User{
        Jobs:               []*firestore.DocumentRef{employeeReference},
    })
```

On this case I used an array of `*DocumentRef`, but even if is a unique `DocumentRef` doesn't work, I also tried to insert as type `DocumentRef` instead of the pointer, and also doesn't work, my `User` type is like that:

```golang
type User struct {
    Jobs               []*firestore.DocumentRef `json:"jobs"`
}
```

There's something that I can do to insert this type of data from go? On Javascript SDK, I remember that is only to insert the `DocumentReference` type directly on object that is achieved, but I'm facing this problem with Golang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with Golang but [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/master/firestore/examples_test.go) you can find many examples.

I wonder if something like the following can give you any hints:

```
_, err := userReference.Set(context.Background(), models.User{
        Jobs:               []*firestore.DocumentRef{client.Doc("/selfManagedEmployees/K4qhd5k1c...")}  
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Was exactly this!